# Gremlin - Adding multiple child vertices in one go - addV and step

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Here is the general theme I want to play with:

- Vertex: "Parent" label
- Edge: "parent_to" label
- Vertex: "Child" label

I am trying to do this by doing the following:

1. Create "parent" vertex and use `as("parent")`
2. Create edge "parent_to"
3. Create "child" vertex
4. `select("parent)`
5. Repeat edge and child vertex steps

Example:

```
g.addV("parent").property("parent_value","value1").as("parent")
    .addE("parent_to")
        .addV("child").property("child_value","value2")
.select("parent")
    .addE("parent_to")
        .addV("child").property("child_value","value3")
```

Problem is this gives me 1 parent vertex with two child vertices, but the edges loop back to and from the parent, leaving the child vertices "orphaned".

I have linked a post that gives me a working pattern, but is it really the best way to handle hierarchy in one query without need for recursion? [Other QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931817/creation-of-graph-of-multiple-nodes-in-gremlin)
Note: Added a level for example's sake

```
g.addV("parent").as("parent")
    .and(
            addV("child").property("child_value","value2")
                .addE("parent_to").from("parent"),
            addV("child").property("child_value","value3").as("child3").and(
                        addV("grandchild").property("gchild_value","value4").addE("parent_to").from("child3"),
                        addV("grandchild").property("gchild_value","value5").addE("parent_to").from("child3")
                    )
                .addE("parent_to").from("parent")
        )
```

Because this will be used on AWS Neptune, I have to add everything into one query to maintain the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close, it is just missing specifying the [from()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#from-step) or [to()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#to-step) steps to tell addE() which vertices to connect.  I this case you probably want to use to() step as shown here.

```
g.addV("parent").
  property("parent_value", "value1").as("parent").
  addE("parent_to").to(addV("child").property("child_value", "value2")).
  select("parent").
  addE("parent_to").to(addV("child").property("child_value", "value3"))
```